# LibGdx crash Failed resolution

Tags: libgdx, crash

I have this app in google play, in my devices the app works great, but google console keeps telling me people are experimenting crashes!

I dont know how to replicate the error, tried with genymotion, using the same devices and no luck.

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap;
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzs.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzs.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzc.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ClientApi.createInterstitialAdManager(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.createInterstitialAdManager(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzac.zzH(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
    at com.myApp.icalc.AndroidLauncher.setUpAds(AndroidLauncher.java:79)
    at com.myApp.icalc.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myApp.icalc-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myApp.icalc-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    ... 26 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 27 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

The error seems to be happening to a few devices. Do someone know how to fix it? and how can I replicate the error so I can be sure I fix it?

Thank you!

EDIT: heres my build.gradle just in case...

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp.icalc"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.myApp.icalc/com.myApp.icalc.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

copying this made me realize that in build.gradle the minSdkversion = 8 and in my manifest minSdkversion = 9
Could it be this?